# loaded div not yet in DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, load, find

I'm using jQuery load() function to load some contents from one div inside the other. It shows up on the browser ok, but when I try to use the function find(), it doesn't find anything, as it doesn't show up in the DOM yet. I've tried printing out the HTML contents of the div (the one that holds the loaded content) just after they're loaded and just before I'm using find() - it shows the HTML that was there before the div with the content was loaded in.

So the question is, how do I look for a certain id in the loaded content if it's not in the DOM yet?

Maybe I could work around this with live() and custom events?

Here's some very simplified code of what is going on:

```
$('#serverctl-server-dc').load('query.php?m=serverctl&q=shelf_view');
console.log($('#srv-1111').html());
```

The generated source does include #srv-1111 element and it does contain html. I'm not getting anything in the console though.

Comment: if you could share/show up the code that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to manipulate the $('#srv-'+maskId) element, so what I've implemented was magical - at least for me:

```
$('#serverctl-server-dc').live('getId', function(){
    $('#srv-'+maskId).parent().css('border','4px solid #AF0200');
});

$('#serverctl-server-dc').load('query.php?m=serverctl&q=shelf_view', function(){
    $('#serverctl-server-dc').trigger('getId');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

"load" is asynchronous. You should put the processing in the callback function parameter of the load request. Only then can you be sure of the inner elements of the DIV being available.

Yes you could use "live()" if you want to process events on the new elements. If you just want to manipulate the new elements though (other than style them with CSS), e.g. replace some of the text with something else, or animate them, you'll need to wait for them to be loaded.

Comment: +1.. Using the callback is indeed the correct way and it's clearly documented in the official page http://api.jquery.com/load/ after "The provided callback, if any, is executed after this post-processing has been performed"

Answer (score 0):

In principle it should find your element but you need to validate the sequence of your actions.

When exactly do you use the find function?

Use Chrome developer tools as it shows you the current manipulated html and not the original file that was loaded.

If more explanation is needed, post your code.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug and debug the script. After you load your contents search for the id to see if it really is there.

HTH